# Equality of records with lists in C# 9.0

Tags: c#, record, equality, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

Today, I was experimenting with the new features in C# 9.0, and I noticed that when I use a record that contains a `List<Point2d>`, two records with the same values in their `List<Point2d>` are not considered equal. `Point2d` is also a record type in this case.

```
public sealed record Point2d
{
    public Point2d(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
}

public sealed record Polyline2d
{
    private readonly List<Point2d> _corners;

    public Polyline2d(IEnumerable<Point2d> corners)
    {
        _corners = new List<Point2d>(corners);
    }
}

        Polyline2d a = new (new Point2d[] { new(0, 0), new(1, 1), new(2, 2)});
        Polyline2d b = new (new Point2d[] { new(0, 0), new(1, 1), new(2, 2) });

        a == b => false
```

If I manually add equality methods for the record and redefine the `Equals()` method, then the records are considered equal again.

```
    public bool Equals(Polyline2d other)
    {
        return other != null && _corners.SequenceEqual(other._corners);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 42;
    }


    a == b => true
```

Is this the correct approach to solve this problem, or are there other considerations that I need to take into account when working with record data types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autogenerated equality comparison for records uses the default equality comparer for all fields (the same has been true for value types since always, btw). And the default equality comparer for `List<T>` is just reference equality. So it is more or less equivalent to:

```
public bool Equals(Polyline2d other)
{
    return other != null && _corners.Equals(other._corners);
}
```

Nothing unexpected and your solution is correct - if you want `SequenceEqual` used you need to define the `Equals` yourself. <s>Also note that you don't need to redefine `GetHashCode`, the compiler still generates its own version even if you specify your own `Equals` (but that autogenerated `GetHashCode` will still use the `List<T>`'s default comparer's `GetHashCode`).</s> **That was some bad advice, thanks Jeremy Lakeman for pointing that out.** If `GetHashCode` returns different values for two instances then `Equals` must return false for them, so you do in fact need to override `GetHashCode` so that sequence-equal lists do not return different hashcodes, which would be the case with the default implementation.

---

Disclaimer: the logic in the synthesised `Equals` is much more complex than this because it actually uses `EqualityComparer<List<Point2d>>.Default` and takes record inheritance into account, but it's irrelevant in this case.

Comment: if `.Equals()` says they are equal, `.GetHashCode()` should return the same value. Generally if you override one, you should override the other. Or you will get surprising results in a `HashSet` / `Dictionary` Key.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You're right, I mixed up the semantics of hashcodes in my head and thought in this case it would be fine, but it really isn't. Amusingly, when I typed the different Equals to my IDE it even gives you a warning CS8851: 'Polyline2d' defines 'Equals' but not 'GetHashCode', so fortunately the compiler is smarter than me and warns about that.